# WPF MVP Pattern and Linq to SQL

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql

I have an application to write in WPF and I’m struggling on what database access to use.

The book I’m reading uses the MVP pattern which is really cool, Ideally I’d like to use this pattern with Linq to SQL but I’m not sure how to go about it; would I still need manually write my entity classes or can I use the Linq to SQL ones that are generated and somehow hook these up within the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the **MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern** which is very popular for WPF because it takes advantage of the excellent data binding capabilities of WPF. Large applications, such as Microsoft Blend have been written using this pattern (that group originally developed the pattern).

You can then use **Linq to SQL to implement your model classes**.